# PDF's with dynamic elements failed with docusign-esign-java

Tags: docusignapi

I am using docusign-esign-java and send a PDF's with dynamic elements (checkbox's text fields) which was generated from pdf-box api. 
I get the below error from docusign api which does not clear what's the issue , except it indicate the fact that PDF can not be processed in docusign end.

com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: {
  "errorCode": "PDF_VALIDATION_FAILED",
  "message": "The validation of the PDF file failed."
}.

Our requirement is recipient should fill out the pff and sign it. 
Is this requirement achievable? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please check if you are able to open PDF generate using pdf-box api before passing it to DocuSign API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Our requirement is recipient should fill out the pff and sign it. Is this requirement achievable?

Yes. But it is usually best to add the check boxes via the DocuSign API or by using a DocuSign template.

You can add them via the pdf but you will have fewer options from that technique.